# Button that creates a new folder in note app

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I achieve this?

[image: note app and added functionality]

I want to make folders within folders.

I have this from another question:

```
class Folder {
  final String name;
  List<Folder>? folders;
  Folder(this.name);
}

class Note {
  List<Folder>? folders;
}
```

```
class FolderViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Folder folder;
  const FolderViewer({Key? key, required this.folder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(folder.name);
  }
}
```

But I don't know how work with that... can you add more to that or give me a different way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
class Folder {
  final String name;
  List<Folder>? folders;
  Folder(this.name);
}
```

You can easily achieve nested folders like this:

```
newFolder = Folder("New Folder")
subFolder = Folder("Sub Folder")

newFolder.folders.add(subFolder)
```

And you can keep on doing it.

Comment: How would I use this for onPressed in a PopupMenuItem? Could you please add more? This is a bit beyond my skill level...

Comment: @LeenaMarie You can create a parent folder and save its object of class `Folder` in a class variable. On pressed you can write a function that makes a object of class `Folder` and adds it to the parent folder. Can you share your code for the part where you're having the trouble?